# Writing a function that takes a vector as input, throws away unwanted values, de-duplicates, and returns respective indexes of original vector

Tags: r, function, vector, duplicates

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a vector and subsets it according to several steps:

1. Throws away any unwanted values
2. Removes duplicates.
3. Returns the *indexes* of the original vector after accounting for steps (1) and (2).

For example, provided with the following input vector:

```r
vec_animals <- c("dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "dolphin", "dolphin")
```

and

```r
throw_away_val <- "cat"
```

I want my function `get_indexes(x = vec_animals, y = throw_away_val)` to return:

```r
# [1] 1 6   # `1` is the index of the 1st unique ("dog") in `vec_animals`, `6` is the index of the 2nd unique ("dolphin")
```

**Another example**

```r
vec_years <- c(2003, 2003, 2003, 2007, 2007, 2011, 2011, 2011)
throw_away_val <- 2003
```

Return:

```r
# [1] 4 6 # `4` is the position of 1st unique (`2007`) after throwing away unwanted val; `6` is the position of 2nd unique (`2011`).
```

#### My initial attempt

The following function returns indexes but doesn't account for duplicates

```r
get_index <- function(x, throw_away) {
  which(x != throw_away)
}
```

which then returns the indexes of the original `vec_animals` such as:

```r
get_index(vec_animals, "cat")
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 6 7
```

If we use this output to subset `vec_animal` we get:

```r
vec_animals[get_index(vec_animals, "cat")]
#> [1] "dog"     "dog"     "dog"     "dog"     "dolphin" "dolphin"
```

You could have suggested to operate on this output such as:

```r
vec_animals[get_index(vec_animals, "cat")] |> unique()
#> [1] "dog"     "dolphin"
```

But no, I need `get_index()` to return the correct indexes right away (in this case `1` and `6`).

---

EDIT

---

A relevant procedure in which we can get the indexes of first occurrences of duplicates is provided with

```r
library(bit64)

vec_num <- as.integer64(c(4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 100, 100))
unipos(vec_num)
#> [1] 1 2 4 8
```

Or more generally

```r
which(!duplicated(vec_num))
#> [1] 1 2 4 8
```

Such solutions would have been great if had not needed to also throw away unwanted values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
get_index <- function(x, throw_away) {
  which(!duplicated(x) & x!=throw_away)
  }

> get_index(vec_animals, "cat")
[1] 1 6
```

Comment: thanks.  you could change to `x!=throw_away` to `!(x %in% throw_away)` if you wanted to discard more than one value

Comment: It would be nice (although not necessary) if you could elaborate on the mechanism why your solution works. I understand that this has to do with `R`'s vectorized operations, but don't have much intuition beyond.

Comment: Look at the how the individual components work.  `duplicated(x)` gives a vector of booleans corresponding to whether each of the elements of `x` is a duplicate of a previous value or not.  `x!=throwaway` is also a vector of booleans corresponding to whether each element is to be thrown away.  `which` then returns the indices of the  elements of `x` that meet both conditions (ie both vectors are `TRUE`).

Comment: So the first `!` negates the entire `&` expression? Or does it negate only `duplicates(x)`?

Comment: The first `!` only negates `duplicated(x)`.  I could have used brackets to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple self-written function that provides the needed information.

```
vec_animals <- c("dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "dolphin", "dolphin")

get_indexes <- function(x, throw_away){
  elements <- (unique(x))[(unique(x)) != throw_away]
  index <- lapply(1:length(elements), function(i) {which(x %in% elements[i]) })
  index2return <- c()
  for (j in 1:length(index)) {
    index2return <- c(index2return, min(index[[j]]))
  }
  return(index2return)
}

get_indexes(x = vec_animals, throw_away = "cat")
[1] 1 6
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach :

```
vec_animals <- c("dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "dolphin", "dolphin")
throw_away_val <- "cat"

my_function <- function(x, y) {
my_df <- data.frame("Origin" = x,
                  "Position" = seq.int(from = 1, to = length(x), by = 1),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
my_var <- which(my_df$Origin %in% y)
if (length(my_var)) {
my_df <- my_df[-my_var,]
}
my_df <- my_df[!duplicated(my_df$Origin),]
return (my_df)
}

my_df <- my_function(vec_animals, throw_away_val)
```